# JRuby String Class Methods Not Available

Tags: ruby, jruby

I can't seem to call any of Java's string methods from within JRuby.  The same style of syntax work for the Math class though.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#! /usr/bin/env jruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'java'

puts java.lang.Math::max(1000,200)
puts java.lang.Math::PI

# this doesn't work 
puts java.lang.String::toUpperCase("we, the people")

# this doesn't work either 
JString = java.lang.String
puts JString.toUpperCase('We, the people')

#toUpperCase exists though, see below
puts java.lang.String.java_class.declarSed_instance_methods
```

Comment: Note that `toUpperCase` is an **instance** method, not a static method (`Math.max` and `Math.PI` are a static method and static member variable of class `Math`). You seem to be calling `toUpperCase` as if it's a static method.

Comment: I assume it's a way to keep interpotability between JRuby and other implementations.

Comment: Thanks, Jesper.  If there is a way to accept your and Gaurav's answers I would.  (I don't see any accept method.)  I was able to mark Gaurav's answer as 'helpful'.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
java.lang.String.new("we, the people").toUpperCase
```

As mentioned by @Jesper, toUpperCase is an instance method with the String class. Using it as a static method will not work.

Also note, the class returned is of native Ruby type.